Create a new column based on other columns for time series data in pandas
I have the following pandas dataframe with columns May, June, and July.



Month
June
July
Aug




June
a
d
g


July
b
e
h


Aug
c
f
i



I want to create a several new columns with a 1 month forecast, 2 month forecasts.
Forecasts



Month
1-M Forecast
2-M Forecast




June
a
d


July
e
h


Aug
i




enter image description here
I tried the following
for i in df.columns:
 df.loc[df['MONTH']==i,i]=None

I expected this loop to return to me the value of the intersection, but got returned None values instead.
enter image description here

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"June": ["a", "b", "c"], "July": ["d", "e", "f"], "Aug": ["g", "h", "i"]},
    index=["June", "July", "Aug"],
)
months = list(df.columns)


def get_m_forecast(df, m, colname):
    df[colname] = ""
    for i, month in enumerate(months):
        if i + m - 1 < len(months):
            df.loc[month, colname] = df.loc[month, months[i + m - 1]]
    return df


df = get_m_forecast(df, m=1, colname="1-M Forecast")
df = get_m_forecast(df, m=2, colname="2-M Forecast")
print(df)

